# Which design pattern to use when multiple inheritance is needed in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a vehicle class, and nice implmented Ship and Plane to check for safety, each class implementing its own safetycheck. World was good.

```
interface Vehicle {
    public void safetyCheck();
}


class Ship implements Vehicle {
    @Override
    public void safetyCheck() {
        //check if number of lifeboats >= number of passengers
    }
}

class Plane implements Vehicle {
    @Override
    public void safetyCheck() {
        //check if oxygen mask is in place.
    }
}
```

But soon a hybrid called seaplane was needed which duplicated safety checks of `Ship` and `Plane`

```
class SeaPlane implements Vehicle {
    @Override
    public void safetyCheck() {
        //check if oxygen mask is in place.
        // && 
       //check if number of lifeboats >= number of passengers
    }
}
```

Which design patterns help in such particular scenarios to reduce code redundancy and make implementation cleaner ?

Comment: I would create a common ancestor for `Plane`, `Ship` and `SeaPlane`, with a parameterized `safetyCheck`, then `Plane` call super with first value of param, `Ship` call super with another value of param and `SeaPlane` call twice, one with both param. (may be using an enum for the param)

Comment: Agreed this is a duplicate. SeaPlane is basically Pegasus in this answer stackoverflow.com/a/21824485/1168342

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without establishing a new interface or class for this case you could use the [Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle.

So your `SeaPlane` could look like this:

```
class SeaPlane implements Vehicle {
    private Vehicle plane,
                    ship;
    @Override
    public void safetyCheck() {
       plane.safetyCheck();
       ship.safetyCheck()
    }
}
```

With a constructor taking a `Plane` and a `Ship` object.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the strategy pattern to separate some behavior of a component from the components definition. Then you could use these behaviors in multiple classes in order to avoid redundancy.

Comment: I dont think the strategy Pattern applies here, since you're not changing the object's type at runtime. You only want to reduce redundancy.